# Socket IO not receiving data in production server

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, socket.io, ejs

I have created a nodejs,express and mongo app, in which I have been using socket.io to fetch realtime data from MongoDB, For example, whenever I add a new post I get the post realtime on my dashboard, this feature is working when I am working on my local environment, but when I try the same thing in my production I get the following error. Please see the screen shot. I have tried all the possible solutions in the StackOverflow community but it didn't work, I am attaching the screenshot of the error and the code.
My Prodcution server is Ubuntu 18.04

[image]
[image]

Socket IO Declaration

`var io = require('socket.io')(2001);`

server.js Code:

```
query.create(Query,async function(err,query){
    if(err){
        req.flash("error","Something went wrong please Retry");
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/form/"+req.body.query.userid); 
    }else{
      
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            io.emit("ADDED_DATA", query);
        }); 
                
                res.redirect("/form/"+req.body.query.userid);
                
           
        }
})
```

dashboard.ejs code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-1fOn6VtTq3PWwfsOrk45LnYcGosJwzMHv+Xh/Jx5303FVOXzEnw0EpLv30mtjmlj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
const socket = io('https://example.com:2001'); //ip and port of server
socket.on("ADDED_DATA", (arg) => {
   console.log(arg); 
}); 
</script>
```

My Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"aes-ecb": "^1.3.10",
"aes-js": "^3.1.2",
"async": "^3.2.0",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"canvas": "^2.6.1",
"connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
"connect-redis": "^5.0.0",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
"crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
"csurf": "^1.11.0",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"ejs": "^2.7.2",
"email-existence": "^0.1.6",
"email-validator": "^2.0.4",
"excel4node": "^1.7.2",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.0",
"faker": "^5.5.3",
"firebase": "^9.6.0",
"firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
"firebaseui": "^5.0.0",
"http": "0.0.1-security",
"https": "^1.0.0",
"method-override": "^3.0.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
"mongoose": "^5.7.11",
"node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
"node-html-parser": "^5.1.0",
"node-rsa": "^1.1.1",
"nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1",
"pdfkit": "^0.11.0",
"qrcode": "^1.5.0",
"randomstring": "^1.1.5",
"redis": "^3.0.2",
"request": "^2.88.2",
"socket.io": "^2.4.1",
"system-commands": "^1.1.7",
"uuid": "^8.3.2"
```

},

Please let me know how to solve this error. I have been working on this for quite a long time. This code works perfectly locally but on production, it is not working. In local I will be using `localhost` instead of example.com it works fine.

Comment: Is the server running and listening to port 2001 on the production server itself and not running on another machine?

Comment: Mongodb is running on default port 20717 on the same server. When I post to the 'create post route' it should create the product and emit the data to dashboard.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson